# PHP form details are not stored in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs

I am creating a form in AngularJS by using which i have to store person details in phpMyAdmin(mysql). But as soon as i hit the submit button after filling the form, the details are not added in database can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

HTML Page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<title> Home </title>
<body>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form>
<br>
<h1 align="left">ID : <input type="text" ng-model="id"></h1>
<h1 align="left">Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></h1>

<h1 align="left">Address : <input type="text" ng-model="address"></h1>

<h1 align="left">Phone : <input type="text" ng-model="phone"></h1>

<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="insertData()" />
</br>
</form>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){

$scope.insertData = function(){
$http.post("insert.php",{
'id':$scope.id, 
'name':$scope.name, 
'address':$scope.address, 
'phone':$scope.phone})
.then(function successCallback(data,status,headers,config) {
console.log(data);
});
}
});
```

PHP code: insert.php

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username   = "root";
 $password   = "bulbul";
 $dbname     = "angularjs";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }


 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $php_array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 $id = $php_array['id'];
 $name = $php_array['name'];
 $address = $php_array['address'];
 $phone = $php_array['phone'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO employee(id,name,address,phone) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bind_param("isss", $id, $name, $address, $phone);
 if ($stmt->execute()) {

  echo "data inserted";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: no no error i am getting

Comment: Try to print `mysql_error()` and post the error. Additionally you should use mysqli or PDO, because mysql is deprecated

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions! They are DEPRECATED, use MySQLi or PDO instead. And use prepared queries to stop being so vulnerable to SQL injection attacks!

Comment: Try debugging first. The issue could be a database one, or the POST request, or the form itself.

Comment: var_dump(mysql_query()) and see what its saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why the form details are not added in database?* well because you have the following error:

> $http.post(...).success is not a function

Make use of your browser console.

The problem is `.success`  $http success and error methods were available in older versions of Angular 1.x, but they've been deprecated for awhile and removed in Angular 1.6. see : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/

You should use `.then()`

This is what u need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<title> Home </title>
<body>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form>
<br>
<h1 align="left">ID : <input type="text" ng-model="id"></h1>
<h1 align="left">Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></h1>

<h1 align="left">Address : <input type="text" ng-model="address"></h1>

<h1 align="left">Phone : <input type="text" ng-model="phone"></h1>

<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="insertData()" />
</br>
</form>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.insertData = function(){
    $http.post("insert.php",{
    'id':$scope.id, 
    'name':$scope.name, 
    'address':$scope.address, 
    'phone':$scope.phone})
    .then(function successCallback(data,status,headers,config) {
    console.log(data);
    });
    }
    });
    </script>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then your insert.php

stop using depreciated functions and stop using dangerous code use prepared statements :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "angularjs";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$id = $data->id;
$name = $data->name;
$address = $data->address;
$phone = $data->phone;

$sql = "INSERT INTO employee(id,name,address,phone) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("isss", $id, $name, $address, $phone);
if ($stmt->execute()) {

    echo "data inserted";
}
?>
```

Comment: hey after doing the updates what you have said... i am getting NOTICE as: ( ! ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\HomeMade\insert.php on line 16.

Comment: @BleedCode show me which line is 16? use my insert.php code as it is just change the server credentials

Comment: $id = $data->id; <- This is the line on which i m getting error. Same ways, i am getting error in $name = $data->name;
$address = $data->address;
$phone = $data->phone;

Comment: post your full code, m not getting any of those errors, its working perfect on my side @BleedCode

Comment: Updated insert.php code used the same which have given

Comment: and used the same frontend as I gave?

Comment: yupp but stilll problem didn't solved

Comment: I still believe u doing something wrong... edit your question with the latest code u have... also clean the browser cache

Comment: tried everything

Comment: honestly m not sure why u getting that, in my side evrything works well

Comment: I have again modified the code,, now i am not getting any error in insert.php but still the form values are not inserted in database.

Comment: check the error log on the server @BleedCode

Answer (score 0):

use .then instead of .success
as .success is deprecated in latest angular 1.x versions

http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-%24https-success/

use die in php code to check any server side issue